# Is there one noun to describe "getting a person to do what you want by threatening to replace them"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need one noun to describe "getting a person to do what you want by threatening to replace them".

I checked the meaning of coercion but it says both force and threatening. First I don't want to include force and second I want threatening specifically of being replaced.

The threat can be active or passive. For example, if someone is a famous artist they can passively influence their employers or partners to do what they want because they know that he or she has enough options for exit.

Example usage: the most effective way to get contractors in this industry to deliver high-quality results in a short period is by [place the word here].

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to express all that in one word.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear any answers but I think it's just a category of bullying or blackmail (although individual cases may be e.g. sexual harassment).

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by an example sentence in which the requested word is placed in context.

Comment: **force** can be any kind of pressure exerted, even the figurative "pressure" of being fired from your job. It need not be physical pressure.

Comment: This is "shape-up-or-ship-out"ment.

Comment: "The most effective way to get contractors in this industry to deliver high-quality results in a short period is by **coercion**".

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for your comment. The definition of coercion is persuasion by force or threat. Even though, the threat part overlaps with my requirement but my issue with this word is (1) it combines both force and threat and (2) the threat is too broad. The specific type of threat I'm looking for is a threat to replace.

Comment: @StuartFthank you for your comment, blackmail may be relevant, but this word is too broad in its scope (i.e., not just apply to replacement)